# Parse from a list with a quote in text

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I want to put these strings in a list, how do I do that? The hold up is the double `""`, found in the first two lines. How can I work around this?

```
scriptTxt = new string[]
{
    "#$language = "VBScript"",
    "#$interface = "1.0"",
    "crt.Screen.Synchronous = True",
    "Sub Main"
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scriptTxt = new string[]
{
    "#$language = \"VBScript\"",
    "#$interface = \"1.0\"",
    "crt.Screen.Synchronous = True",
    "Sub Main"
};
```

Or

```
scriptTxt = new string[]
{
    @"#$language = ""VBScript""",
    @"#$interface = ""1.0""",
    "crt.Screen.Synchronous = True",
    "Sub Main"
};
```

Comment: You'll need another @ sign on the second string as the 1.0 has quotes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes with a backslash. (An apostrophe is a ')

```
scriptTxt = new string[]
{
    "#$language = \"VBScript\"",
    "#$interface = \"1.0\"",
    "crt.Screen.Synchronous = True",
    "Sub Main"
};
```